# pass multiple build args to docker via file

Tags: bash, docker

I would like to be able to pass multiple build arguments to docker file, and do this via file.
I have found a solution
https://ilhicas.com/2018/11/03/docker-build-with-build-arg-wit-multiple-arguments.html

My `build.args` file:

```
SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(< ~/.ssh/mia_key)"
CORE_CONFIG_NAME=staging.yml
```

so what I do now:

```
$old_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
docker build --squash -t automations \
  $(for i in `cat build.args`; do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="";IFS=$old_IFS) .
```

and I got

```
unknown flag: --build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY
See 'docker build --help'.
```

while

```
echo $(for i in `cat build.args`; do out+="--build-arg $i " ; done; echo $out;out="";IFS=$old_IFS)
```

gives what I expected

```
--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(< ~/.ssh/mia_key)" --build-arg CORE_CONFIG_NAME=staging.yml
```

I believe this may be related to quotes, like I call

```
docker build --squash -t automations \
      "--build-arg SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(< ~/.ssh/mia_key)" --build-arg CORE_CONFIG_NAME=staging.yml" .
```

How can I resolve this?
I have to get rid of quotes, or find another solution for passing arguments

Comment: You want to pass the string literally `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY="$(< ~/.ssh/mia_key)"` or you want to execute the `$(< ...)` and pass the resulting content?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use backticks `. Use `$(...)` instead. [Bash hackers wiki obsolete deprecated syntax](https://wiki-dev.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete).

Do not `for i in $(cat)`. Use a `while IFS= read -r` loop. [How to read a file line by line in bash](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001).

Use bash arrays to properly quote arguments.

```
args=()
while IFS= read -r i; do args+=("--build-arg" "$i"); done < build.args
docker build --squash -t automations "${args[@]}" .
```

Alternatively you could with enough safe handling use `printf %q` to properly escape and quote the arguments and use a command substitution, but I advise to use bash arrays when possible

```
docker build --squash -t automations $(while IFS= read -r i; do printf "%q %q " --build-arg "$i"; done < build.args) .
```

If you want to execute the `$(<...)` command substitution, it get's harder, because that needs a fully shell-aware parsing of the file. So the file needs to be `source`d. Then iterate over the environments variable and pass their contents properly escaped:

```
docker build --squash -t automations $(
    source build.args;
    for i in CORE_CONFIG_NAME SSH_PRIVATE_KEY; do
         printf "%q %q=%q " --build-arg "$i" "${!i}";
    done
) .
```

Assuming your file is well structured, you could filter the file to extract the strings in front `=` with maybe like-ish `sed -n '/=/{s/=.*//;p}' and have the list of environment variables generated almost automatically.